# Modal closes when clicked outside (angularjs-- plunker attacked)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I tried various solutions posted online for how to disable modal closing when we clicked outside the modal. I didnt find a working solution.

Can someone please let me know how to achieve it in my case.

http://plnkr.co/edit/DX7My1zuQEeeQTfDOHi9?p=preview

Heres the plunker

```
$scope.modal = {
title: "Enter Details",
html: true,
show: true,
backdrop:'static',
keyboard:false
};
```

set this parameter. Yet cldnt get it working.

Comment: A side note on the code you didn't include here, `document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');` is an XSS disaster waiting to happen.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara- i am not sure wat its for. can you pls explain

Comment: IDK why you have it, but using `location` blindly like this a common [DOM Based XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/DOM_Based_XSS) attack vector.

Comment: removed that part of the code. updated plunker attached

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use data attributes on the button you are clicking to open the modal, it will wire the modal through bootstrap to not close. like this:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-md btn-primary" data-animation="am-flip-x" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" data-template-url="modal/docs/modal.demo.tpl.html" data-placement="center" bs-modal="modal">Open modal</button>
```

Notice I added these 2 data attributes:

```
data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false"
```

Here is your Plunker code edit to keep the modal open:
http://plnkr.co/edit/v92LToGz9yc3gCV8tr04?p=preview